# Can you have multiple cohorts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The Leadership feat grants the character a cohort when they take it. 
Feats like [Imperial / Taldan Knight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/imperial-knight) say "gain a cohort as if you had selected the leadership feat".

Do these stack, giving you multiple cohorts?

Answer (score 5):

### With a GM willing to have the party consist of the PCs plus several additional long-term NPCs, a character willing to commit the feats can have several cohorts

The feat [Imperial Knight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/imperial-knight) (né Taldor Knight) does, indeed, grant a cohort as if with the feat [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final). If a character takes *both* those feats and wants a second cohort, then the player must have an uncomfortable conversation with the GM about the meaning of the phrase [*as if*](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2s5kq?AS-IF), which is unclear in this context. (Bring cookies because the GM always wins.)

Assuming the conversation ends in the player's favor, the character *can* have 2 cohorts; as the cohort granted by the feat Imperial Knight must be a halfling or human commoner, expert, or warrior, having a second cohort—one with with *non*-NPC classes—seems less an indulgence and more of a kindness on the GM's part. (Although an expert with maximum ranks in the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) can contribute throughout his career if properly equipped.)

Note that the feat [Squire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/squire) (available at level 3) and the feat [Torchbearer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/torchbearer) (available at level 5) *also* grant cohorts, but, unlike the feat Imperial Knight, *those* feats actually *become* the feat Leadership (at levels 8 and 7, respectively). Unfortunately, having the feat Leadership multiple times is the same as having it once, but [retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining) the duplicates may be an option.

The biggest problem with the *combination* of the feats Imperial Knight, Squire, and Torchbearer is that the feat Leadership specifies a lone cohort. When the character is levels 1 through 6 all three cohorts have unique methods of recruiting dismissed cohorts, but after the feats Squire and Torchbearer transform into the feat Leadership, 
the GM may rule that replacing *any* of the three cohorts is done *via* the feat Leadership, which limits a character to a lone cohort. This likely makes replacing a cohort lost when the character's level 8 or higher impossible while *any* cohort remains.<sup>1</sup> But, as always in weird corner cases the rules don't cover, ask the GM.

A particularly legalistic player could even petition the GM to allow his evil character to take all three of the above feats *and* at level 7 take the feat [Vile Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/vile-leadership) to add a *fourth* cohort.<sup>2</sup> (Note that a player would have to be extremely persuasive for *me* to permit his character to take both the feats Leadership and Vile Leadership even if a rules technicality allows such a combination.)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Cohorts, even if dead, don't appear to be dismissed *automatically*. Thus a character whose squire or torchbearer or *whatever* cohort dies needn't recruit anew as long as the dead cohort isn't dismissed. Under this ruling, however, a character must be forever content with such a cohort or risk losing it forever when the cohort's dismissed.
<sup>**2**</sup> The feat Vile Leadership says, "Once you take this feat, you cannot take the Leadership feat without retraining your feat selection." However, the rules lawyer in me notes that only the GM (and, if any, proper order of operations for feats becoming other feats) stops a character from taking (or having one of the character's other feats turn into) the feat Leadership *then* taking the feat Vile Leadership, getting a cohort and another batch of followers from both normal and villainous Leadership.

Comment: This [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/176400/8610) mentions the feats [Page](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Page) *et al.* from *Ultimate Intrigue* (2016) that also grant cohorts, some of them without the hassle of later becoming the actual Leadership feat.

Answer (score 2):

By strict RAW, yes, there's no clause there that says they don't stack, nor any rule elsewhere that prevents it, so each feat has its own effect separately, and the end result is two cohorts on the same character. Note the contrast with [Personal Guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/necromancers-of-the-northwest/general-feats---3rd-party---necromancers-of-the-northwest/personal-guardian). Most feats that provide cohorts have some sort of restriction specifically to prevent this, but the one you cited has no such clause or prerequisite.

At most tables, this kind of thing is book-throwing bait, so I'd recommend being careful what group you try it with.

Comment: I wouldn't use a 3rd party feat to interpret RAW.

Comment: @MrTumnus I didn't, I used the feat only to demonstrate the difference; I determined that there was a difference in the first place independently of it, though I guess I can see how the way I phrased it makes that a bit unclear. If I come up with a better phrasing, I'll switch it.

Comment: As for picking a better example, the one mentioned in the OP and Leadership itself seem to be the only Paizo ones that grant cohorts. Others that do so are pretty much all 3pp

Comment: No, if that was the case, it would have something along the lines of: "Special: You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects do not stack. Each time you take the feat, <effect for buying multiple times>."
Leadership says: "This feat enables you to attract a loyal cohort and a number of devoted subordinates who assist you." <--- The feat enables you, it doesnt grant you a cohort.

Comment: @ShadowKras Who said anything about taking any one feat multiple times? We're all talking about taking two different feats, each of them one time. There's no "You can take this multiple times" clause, because you *can't* take it multiple times. You can, however, take it one time, and also take the other feat one time, and have both of them do their respective effects separately, the end result of which is that you have one PC with two cohorts.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon I wont bother discussing it unless you are willing to discuss it instead of "fight it" (as looks clear to me when you begin a reply with "who said anything").
But just in case we are willing to discuss it: Everytime (so far in all hardcovers) that the rules mentioned "as if", it meant you got the benefits as if you had that other feature. Meaning that if you got something that granted a bonus to attacks as if you had weapon focus, you could also qualify for weapon specialization.

Comment: For reference: See the recent FAQ and discussions about size changes and "as if your size was one category larger", which caused a lot of rage on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

If 3rd-party material is allowed in your game and if you are ever interested in playing a psion, I highly recommend looking into the [Thrallherd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-prestige-classes/thrallherd) prestige class. In addition to increasing the potency of certain mind-affecting spells and telepathy, it also gives you a more powerful version of the leadership feat. You'll end up with two full-fledged cohorts through this class' abilities. If I'm not mistaken, this class' Leadership-esque ability can pair up with Vile Leadership.

Answer (score 0):

A slight correction: feats Squire, Weapon bearer, Page, Groom and Light bearer all give an extra cohort. However, only the Squire feat becomes the Leadership feat automatically. Weapon bearer, Page, Groom and Light bearer each say the following: "At 7th level, you CAN swap this feat for the Leadership feat." CAN, as in has-the-option but-is-not-required-to swap it for Leadership feat.
So, you can ignore the Squire feat and all the tangling with followers and just have 4 cohorts from the other feats. These are also nice feats, because the cohorts received from them explicitly belong to player classes, not NPC classes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I'm having trouble finding the feats Weapon Bearer, Page, Groom, and Light Bearer. Can this answer link to those feats? Also, answers are usually better received when they stand alone; I recommend removing from this one that it's a *correction* — it provides new, useful information (if I can find those feats!). Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!